# Socat Windows serial port access

Tags: serial-port, tunnel, socat

I want to root my serial COM10 to LAN --> LAN to COM12

I therefor need the equivalent command for windows version of socat:

```
socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:23000,reuseaddr,fork /dev/ttyS0
```

What do I have to enter under Windows instead of **/dev/ttyS0** if I want to access my COM10?

Sender  : socat -d -d -d TCP4:localhost:23000 **/dev/ttyS1**

Receiver: socat -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:23000 **/dev/ttyS2**

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use standard Linux name convention:
/dev/ttyS0 is equivalent to COM1
/dev/ttyS1 ~ COM2
... so **COM10** should be **/dev/ttyS9**.

http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-posixdevices